# How to avoid having BAL dependent on DAL due to DI Container binding requirements?

Tags: c#, .net, ninject

My application consists of three projects. Core, DAL and BAL.

Core contains Domain  objects (Customer, Order, Product). It also contains basic IRepository interface IRepository`<T>.`

DAL contains EntityFramework specific  stuff. It also contain Concrete Repositories ( CustomerRepository, OrderRepository, ProductRepository). I added these concrete repositories  here as they depend on DbContext (which is EF Specific)

Now my BAL should only have dependency on Core and no dependency on DAL. I have added a dependency on NInject in this project. However, I still need to tell Ninject that it should resolve IRepository`<Customer>` as CustomerRepository and that is forcing me to add DAL dependency here. Is there anyway of avoid adding dependency on DAL in my BAL Project?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would normally do your container registration at your [composition root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot.aspx), which would be typically at bootstrap and that code would be contained in your web or desktop assembly, not your assembly that contains your business/domain objects.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Any sample implementations will be appreciated as this link you provided doesn't have any sample. I guess I will have to buy that book to get samples :)

Comment: +1 @palmsnow You'd be insane not to get 'that book' - it is _the_ book for this sort of thing and will have you figuring this stuff out from first principles in a flash. Stop wasting your time and order it now!

Comment: I already ordered it but amazon free shipping will take ~5 days to deliver. Until then I will appreciate if someone can point to reasonable tutorial + code example with it. I am struggling to instantiate CustomRepository in BAL without adding a reference to DAL.

Comment: Is this an MVC web project? Then typically you would use a custom controller factory to have controller dependencies resolved via your container. The registration code would go in your global.asax file.

Comment: No. Its not an MVC project. Most of the googling result provides examples of using it in MVC project. However in this case its the N-tier architecture. That will be a service layer on top of BL layer that can be consumed by different types of client. Any suggestion (preferably with some examples) on how to do it this type of scenario?

Comment: Is this WCF, WebAPI etc? It might be easier to set up another question with an example of your code - what you've tried and what's not working

Comment: added question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12555241/depndency-injection-in-bal-without-adding-a-project-reference-to-dal